# Adding Fulfillment to Shopify orders

Tags: c#, json, shopify, fulfillment

This is my code in adding Fulfillment to Shopify orders but the converted json is not as expected.

```
Fullfillment product = new Fullfillment();
product.status = "success";
product.tracking_number = orderSent.TrackingNo;

List<LineItems> items = new List<LineItems>();
foreach (var item in orderSent.OrderLines)
{
   LineItems line = new LineItems();
   line.id = item.ProductName;
   items.Add(line);
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
json = "{ \"fulfillment\": " + json + "}";

var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
json = json + "{ \"line_items\": " + json1 + "}";
```

And this the converted json from this code:

```
{ "fulfillment": {
    "id":0,
    "status":"success",
    "tracking_number":"xxxx12222",
    }}{ 
    "line_items": [
    {
    "id":"1234566645"
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I turned like this:

```
{
  "fulfillment": {
    "tracking_number": null,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "id": 466157049,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Model:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Fullfillment
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public long id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tracking_number")]
        public string tracking_number { get; set; }
    }

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class LineItems
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

These are the models for Fulfillment and Line Items.

Thank you in advance for giving advices and help.

Comment: Where is the class def for `Fullfillment` & `LineItems`?

Comment: please share your c# code for Api fullfillment request

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    fullfillment = new
    {
        product.tracking_number,
        line_items = items.Select(x => new
        {
            x.id,
            quantity = 1
        })
    }
});
```

That gives me:

```
{
    "fullfillment" : {
        "tracking_number" : "xxxx12222",
        "line_items" : [{
                "id" : "1234566645",
                "quantity" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

I started with this code to build up the JSON above:

```
Fullfillment product = new Fullfillment();
product.status = "success";
product.tracking_number = "xxxx12222";

List<LineItems> items = new List<LineItems>();

LineItems line = new LineItems();
line.id = "1234566645";
items.Add(line);
```

Obviously you need to fill in your specific data.

Comment: I'll have this json data:

Comment: { "fulfillment": {
"id":0,
"status":"success",
"tracking_number":"000000000000",
"line_items":[
{
"id":"0000000"
}
]
}
}

Comment: And got this response: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.

Comment: @Jen143 - That JSON isn't the same as you started with. Can you explain more clearly where that came from and how that relates to my answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity Wrong approach. You are asking him to tinker his model without fixing the obvious issue. If the model must have those extra fields, then OP should be asked to create a ViewModel (considering this is MVC) for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Change your classes like below.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Fulfillment fulfillment { get; set; }
}

public class Fulfillment
{
    public string tracking_number { get; set; }
    public Line_Items[] line_items { get; set; }
}

public class Line_Items
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class JsonTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var root = new Rootobject();
        root.fulfillment = new Fulfillment();
        root.fulfillment.tracking_number = "xxxx12222";
        root.fulfillment.line_items = new List<Line_Items>() { new Line_Items() { id = "1234566645", quantity = 1 } }.ToArray();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

This will give you this json.

```
{
  "fulfillment": {
    "tracking_number": "xxxx12222",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "id": "1234566645",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This would be very useful in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Fulfillment fulfillment { get; set; }
}

public class Fulfillment
{
    public string tracking_number { get; set; }
    public Line_Items[] line_items { get; set; }
}

public class Line_Items
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class JsonTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var root = new Rootobject();
        root.fulfillment = new Fulfillment();
        root.fulfillment.tracking_number = "xxxx12222";
        root.fulfillment.line_items = new List<Line_Items>() { new Line_Items() { id = "1234566645", quantity = 1 } }.ToArray();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```